# Speech Language Recognition issues on Android

Tags: android, android-studio, speech-recognition, speech-recognition-api

I'm currently working on an Android application using SpeechRecognizer provided by Google. However, this recognizer only uses the default language of the device, and not languages provided with RecognizerIntent.ADD_EXTRA_LANGUAGES :

```
speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.FRENCH);
speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.EXTRA_ADDITIONAL_LANGUAGES",new String[]{"fr});
```

This code for example won't use French for recognition but will use english instead because it is the device's language. But I need it to work in French.

I know this issue has been already asked multiple times, but it was a pretty long time ago, and I would like to know if anyone know if this bug has been fixed since, or how to fix it? And if it has not been fixed yet, if anyone has any workaround/API/Service to create a voice language recognition application on Android?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Huawei [ML Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-mlkit?ha_source=hms1) may help with your issue.

Huawei provided [Text to speech (TTS)](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/ml-tts-0000001050068169?ha_source=hms1) can convert text information into audio output in real time.Rich timbres, and volume and speed options are supported to produce more natural sounds and **supports French**.

For Detail,pls kindly refer [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/service-introduction-0000001050040017?ha_source=hms1).

You can also use the sample code to quickly understand the Android APIs provided by HUAWEI ML Kit and how to use the APIs. See [ML Kit Android Sample Code](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Examples/sample-code-0000001050265470?ha_source=hms1).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I've look into the documentation, and it provides Text To Speech, or text recognition, but no Speech To Text with a Language Recognition in it (without any predefined language). Do you know if it's possible?

Comment: Maybe [Automatic Speech Recognition](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/ml-asr-0000001050066212-V5#ZH-CN_TOPIC_0000001050710194__section699935381711) or  [Real-Time Transcription](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/real-time-transcription-0000001054964200-V5) are what you need?Pls kindly refer that.Hope it will help.

Comment: BTW,they both support French.